# Test for a difference between rates of occurrences per day

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I have two populations of earthquakes that happened in the same area, the Mediterranean Sea, but in different time periods. The first gives me a rate of 27 per day, and the second 40. How can I test whether this difference is significant?

Comment: do you have the daily # of occurances over a period of time (say a decade)?

Comment: Yes. The first population is the general one; twelve years of observations.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the question you are asking is how to check whether observations of 2 different Poisson processes have different means. Several possibilities are given here:

[Checking if two Poisson samples have the same mean](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9561/checking-if-two-poisson-samples-have-the-same-mean)

Comment: Can you expand on this? Otherwise, it should probably be a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the reference; it really helped me understand what I am looking for.