# Test for equality of means of two paired count variables

Tags: hypothesis-testing, poisson-distribution

Is there any significance test to compare count data measured at pre and post from the same subjects? For example, compare the number of car accidents of a group of drivers at their first year of driving and second year of driving. If we assume that:

$Y_{i1} \sim Poisson (\lambda_1); Y_{i2} \sim Poisson (\lambda_2)$

How may we test the following hypothesis when $Y_{i1}$ and $Y_{i2}$ are paired:
$H_0: \lambda_1 = \lambda_2 $.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9561/checking-if-two-poisson-samples-have-the-same-mean and http://www.ucs.louisiana.edu/~kxk4695/JSPI-04.pdf

Comment: @a_statistician Neither of those references appears to apply to paired data.

Comment: "from the same subjects" This phrase is not very clear. Suppose you observed 100 drivers in first year, in second year you still follow-up these 100 drivers. Question is what kind of data you have, just counts of accidents during two different  year, $Y_1$ and  $Y_2$? or you keep the record for each driver separately, such as $(Y_{i1}, Y_{i2}), i = 1,...,100$. For first situation, the linked method works. for second situation, Poisson regression in needed.

Comment: 1. Your title asks about equality of *variables* but your body text is about equality of their means (and by extension, their distributions).  Please edit your title to reflect what you're actually asking. 2. You will probably need some kind of model for the joint distribution so any kind of application-specific information that would help narrow that selection may be important.

Comment: @Glen_b 1. Updated. 2. I am not sure how to find a joint pmf when they are paired. It would not be a problem if the two variables are independent as sum of two poisson follow a poisson with mean ($\lambda1 + \lambda2$).

Comment: I'm not asking you to specify a joint pdf, but for any *application-specific information* that would help narrow that selection of a pdf. There's many ways to specify correlated Poissons. We can make guesses at reasonable models but they may not suit the specifics of your application.

Comment: I think it might be worth trying to model this problem in the context of a panel model and check for the significance of the relevant coefficient to test the aforementioned hypothesis.